# Setting Up SSH SOCKs Proxy on Raspian

Tags: ssh, networking, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunneling, socks

Ok, initial Deets
Update: Tried wiping the Pi and retrying, I unfortunately got similar results. Any help out there?

- Working using Putty on Windows 10
- Connecting to a Raspberry pi 3 on my local network
- Running Raspian Buster 9-26
- Have DDNS Setup and working ( Things Like Nextcloud and OpenVPN are setup and working)

I tried setting up an inital SOCKs Proxy thinking it would be on a similar level of difficulty. 
I changed the default listening port for SSH following /[default SSH port](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-ssh-port-on-linux-or-unix-server/)
I confirmed it's listening by running

`sudo netstat -antp`

I got confirmation of 3 ports listening:22,80 and 8080

[image: listen Confirmation]

Next I tried to setup the tunnel to run the proxy.

```
ssh -D 8123 -f -C -q -N pi@example.com
```

I tried to verify that the process was up by trying both

```
ps aux | grep ssh
```

&

```
ps aux | grep PORTNUM
```

Where PORTNUM was a random number like 9001

I was expecting some sort of output like [THIS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel). Where I'd see -D and the applicable port, but I never got any extra line items from that command, and the explicit port ones only showed the default result, see below.

[image: SSH ex]

[image: port ex]

I also tried running the SSHD command but it kept telling me I had an extra argument in the form of the port i wanted it to run on.

Can someone try to guide me or point me to some other resources?